AWS EventBridge Rules don't trigger immediately
My service emits EventBridge events, for use by other services.
To test this at the integration level I create an SQS queue and add a new EventBridge rule with a target mapping the event to my queue. I then call my service, and inspect the events on the queue to ensure they're correct.
However sometimes this fails because no messages appear on the queue. I assume here I'm falling foul of timings, AWS in the PutRule documentation say:

When you create or update a rule, incoming events might not immediately start matching to new or updated rules. Allow a short period of time for changes to take effect.

I've tried various ways to work around this, but nothing seems to work reliably except waiting for ten seconds after adding the rule, but I hate sleeping in tests because it just slows them down.
I've tried sending a test event, and waiting for that to be received on the queue, before calling the service, but even that doesn't seem 100% reliable.
Can anyone suggest a reliable way to check whether the rule is being applied?
